# Is it possible to display context of the search result in gcp logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

Just like `grep` command can show the context of matching lines with `--context`, `--after-context` and `--before-context` options, Can we display near by log entries in GCP Logging ?

Comment: Try [Pin log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface#pin-logs). **Scroll to log entry:** Bring the log entry into the current Query results pane and view the pinned log entry in the context of nearby logs.

Comment: This suits my need, Can you please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Pin log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface#pin-logs). Scroll to log entry: Bring the log entry into the current Query results pane and view the pinned log entry in the context of nearby logs.